# Extract Apache environment variable "REMOTE_USER" works only with SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, http-headers, single-sign-on, mod-auth-kerb

We are using Apache with `mod_auth_kerb` to authenticate our users configured in an Active Directory. While trying to extract `REMOTE_USER` from the Environment Variables I observed something strange - I was able to retrieve the user when SSL is enabled by loading `mod_ssl` library, but gave me **"null"** value for non-SSL variable.

Here are the configurations for my Apache Server:

```
<Location /my-site-page>
AuthType Kerberos
AuthName "Kerberos Login"
KrbMethodNegotiate on
KrbMethodK5Passwd on
KrbSaveCredentials on
KrbLocalUserMapping off
KrbAuthRealms MY.REALM.COM
KrbServiceName Any
Krb5KeyTab /path/to/my/keytab

RequestHeader set X-REMOTE-USER %{REMOTE_USER}e
RequestHeader append X-REMOTE-USER %{REMOTE_USER}s
```

As I understand from Apache [Mod Header Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)

> %{VARNAME}e   The contents of the environment variable VARNAME.
>   %{VARNAME}s   The contents of the SSL environment variable VARNAME, if mod_ssl is enabled.

I tried by both turning SSL on and off, and here are the results that I see
**when SSL is enabled**

```
X-REMOTE-USER: (null), harman
```

**when SSL is disabled**

```
X-REMOTE-USER: (null), (null)
```

Comment: Are you using internet explorer? Is the Security zone configuration allowing non-https sites?

Comment: @msg I use Chrome, but that too uses IE configs. The property `Display mixed content` is set to `Prompt`.

Comment: Under "Trusted sites" should be an option to require SSL. If that's the case the browser won't be sending auth headers over a plain connection I think.

Comment: @msg Under `Trusted Sites` it says `Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone.` which was checked but my site was not listed there. However, I unchecked but the result was still the same.